# Посмотреть исходный код Java классов в Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Возможно ли как-то в Eclipse просмотреть исходный код Java класса без использования комбинации Click+CTRL? 
Скажем, я не хочу создавать новый Java проект, создавать новый класс, объявлять переменную нужного типа, в шапке класса импортировать нужные пакеты, и только потом использовать Click+CTRL для того, чтобы открыть исходный код интересующего класса. Гораздо удобнее, если бы в Eclipse был некоторый поиск, где я мог бы прописать название класса и сразу же его открыть.

Comment: **без использования комбинации Click+CTRL?** -- силой мысли?

Answer (score 1):

Быстрый поиск по классам в Eclipse возможен при помощи комбинации клавиш CTRL+SHIFT+T